# Mocking classes that are properties of an object imported from a package with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have the following scenario:

- In my .js file I import the default export of a package *foo*
- This export has two properties *Bar* and *Baz*, they are both ES6 classes
- In my .test.js file I now want to mock these two classes and spy on their constructors

The .js code looks roughly like this:

```
import foo from 'foo/dist/foo.min';
const { Bar, Baz } = foo;
...
const fooBar = new Bar();
```

In my .test.js file I now mock the package like this:

```
jest.mock('foo/dist/foo.min');
```

The automatic mock works as expected, but of course does not allow me to spy on the constructors of Bar and Baz which is what I would want.

I have tried to simply do this in my .test.js file:

```
import foo from 'foo/dist/foo.min';
jest.mock('foo/dist/foo.min');
foo.Bar = jest.fn();
foo.Baz = jest.fn();
```

But this does not seem to do anything, my fake jest.fn() constructors never get called.

I have read this page in the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html but it seems to assume the the ES6 class to be mocked is being exported directly from a module, and is inside the project and not an npm package.

Automatic mock does not work for me because the classes are not exported themselves.

- I can't use `mockImplementation()` on my foo package, since it is not a function, right?
- I don't see a way to do a manual mock because it is a npm package.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

- `babel-jest` hoists calls to `jest.mock` so they happen first.
- The [automatic mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) created by `Jest` reflects the structure of the module.

So calling `jest.mock('foo/dist/foo.min');` means that `Jest` will auto-mock that module for any code that runs during that test, and the auto-mock will reflect the structure of the original module.

---

It looks like your code calls the `Bar` constructor *as soon as it runs*.

This means the following test should work:

```
import foo from 'foo/dist/foo.min';  // foo is already auto-mocked...
import './code';  // import your code (which calls the Bar constructor)

jest.mock('foo/dist/foo.min');  // ...because this runs first

test('constructor was called', () => {
  expect(foo.Bar).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
})
```

---

It looks like your test didn't work because you set `foo.Bar = jest.fn();` *after* your code had run (overwriting the earlier `spy` that *did* get called when your code ran).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brian, that works for me!
I do actually call the code that runs the Bar constructor inside the test block, I didn't realize that automock already recursively mocks all properties, very useful.